# Merge [helm3] into [kubernetes-helm]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Wiki excerpt of [helm3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm3) states that [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm) should be used instead, as version 3 is the only actual version.

> Version 3 is the only currently-supported version of the Kubernetes Helm deployment tool. Use [kubernetes-helm] instead of this tag.

Since [helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm) is already a synonym for [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm), I believe [helm3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm3) should be simply merged into [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm) without synonym creation.

Answer (score 6):

I've been doing this at small scale already and would support a larger effort.  I wrote the tag wiki text you quote in the question.

From a topical-to-SO standpoint there are very few differences between Helm 2 and Helm 3.  In particular the templating language (which has functions, loops, variables, ... and in my mind is unquestionably "programming") is all but identical.  Some older questions covered migration off of the in-cluster "Tiller" component, and there are a couple of extremely specific features (library charts, the `lookup` function) that only exist in Helm 3.  But that's kind of it.

[kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm) is older and better tied to the [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) domain (as distinct from [emacs-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs-helm)).  Also, there isn't a [helm2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm2).  Getting rid of [helm3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helm3) seems right to me.